# How to call Python Script from class in Symfony

Tags: python, php, symfony

I'm wondering how I can call a python script from a class in Symfony. I keep getting an error that it can't locate the script.

```
May 28 13:54:13 |INFO | PHP    python: can't open file 'Request.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The code is as followed:

```
        $python = shell_exec("python Request.py");
        echo $python;
```

The script is outside the symfony project, but I'm not quite sure how to get the path relative to the class file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = shell_exec("pwd");
echo $path;
```

Should show you your current directory.

And I would suggest using Symfony Process Component https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html